# ANSIC IPC message queue What is the type's meaning in struct msgbuf

Tags: unix, ipc, message-queue, ansi-c

As the title saying, I have a trouble with getting clear about the meaning of struct  msgbuf's member variable "type"

```
struct msgbuf
{
    long type;
    char text[100];
};
```

I have no idea about when can it be used and for what, so can anyone give me a hand please....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is related `msgsnd()` and `msgrcv()` calls, then:

You can freely use it however you want.
Except one rule: it must be greater than zero.

`msgrcv()` call have an option (parameter `msgtyp`) to receive a message of wanted type from the queue. See more information from [manpage of msgsnd](https://linux.die.net/man/2/msgsnd):

> If msgtyp is 0, then the first message in the queue is read.
>
> If msgtyp is greater than 0, then the first message in the queue of
> type msgtyp is read, unless MSG_EXCEPT was specified in msgflg, in
> which case the first message in the queue of type not equal to msgtyp
> will be read.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out just after asking this question, hah